# How can I find the absolute value of a vector given in a specific form

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

Looking forward to seeing if anyone can help me with this.

How can I find the absolute value of a vector given in this form:

$ \vec{v_1} = 2\vec{a} + 3\vec{b}$

As you can see it's not the typical $x\hat{i} + y\hat{j} + z\hat{k}$ form nor the $(x,y,z)$ form, so I can't really use the formula directly. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know the components of $\vec a $ and $\vec b$?

Comment: No. The problem consists in 4 such vectors ( v1,v2,v3,v4), perpendicular two by two ( v1 with v2, and v3 with v4 ). And I'm asked to calculate the angle between the vectors a and b. So I figured there must be a way to find the absolute value of these.

Comment: You should provide those details in your question in the first place. They are the keys to its solution. This particular problem and ones like it have come up quite a few times on this site. A search should turn them up.

Comment: I have searched and I really couldnt find them. I wouldn't have asked otherwise :(